# Unexpected end of JSON input in Next.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

I'm fetching data from `/api/notes/1` and receive this:

```json
{
"id":1,
"author":1,
"title":"Pierwsza notka",
"excerpt":"Taka tam notka, bla bla bla",
"body":"Pirwsza notka elo",
"private":1,
"created_at":"2021-04-07T12:59:59.000Z",
"updated_at":"2021-04-07T12:59:59.000Z"
}
```

Which is fine and dandy, but when I pass it into Next's `getStaticProps`:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const res = await fetch(`${config.apiURL}/notes/${params.id}`);
  const post = await res.json();

  return { props: { post } };
}
```

It returns an error:

```
FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/api/notes/1 reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Have you checked on what the actual HTTP response body looks like in the browser "Network" developer tool?

Comment: Check your network console: is the request actually going through properly and is the response the JSON object above?

Comment: Can you try switching out `const post = await res.json();` to `const post = await res.text()` and console.logging post?

Comment: @JohanLindskogen When `res.text()` `post` is just an empty string. What's strange, that the fetch goes smooth when running it in Chrome Devtools console. @Pointy @Chloe_Anderson Also, the request is not in Network tab.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was my fault. The fetch returned 401 Unauthorized with no body.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Status is 200 in your Network Tab. If its not (maybe 500) then you will have to check the URI you are fetching or that the server is responding...

[image: Network Tab of Chrome Browser showing Activity when viewing page]

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got this error in Next 14.1 because I had an oversight and was trying to get a request body from a GET request:

```js
export async function GET(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json();
}
```

Changing this to a post request fixed it for me:

```js
export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json();
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score -1):

Your Response `res` from

```js
const res = await fetch(`${config.apiURL}/notes/${params.id}`);
```

is empty or anything that cloud not be parsed into Json.